# How to compare R-squared and beta coefficients from two separate regression analyses?

Tags: r-squared, regression-coefficients

What is the best way to test whether R-squared from one regression analysis is significantly different from the R-squared of another regression analysis? Is the answer to the first question similar if you wanted to test significant differences between two beta coefficients from two separate regression analyses?

Comment: You might wish to ask yourself why you would want to test R squared of two regressions. What would it tell you? Beta coefficients are not difficult to compare. One method would be to just generate the 95% CI. If they don't overlap between the regressions, you can be certain that the estimates are significantly different. If they do, then they might or might not be. Again, though, why are you looking at this?